# Get all data from server in one file and reuse at all in application

Tags: android

I want to get all data in one activity at starting of activity and then use that data in all other activity.Like get all user information,all contacts from phone and compare that with server data etc.So can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of data is this? XML, JSON, binary blob, csv?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what specific problems are you encountering? Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before asking questions.

Comment: i have tried to use the async class for get the data from server but it is use for calling one api but i want to call other api also then how can i use that async.

Comment: and also i want to show the progressdialog continuesly till the all different api call and get data are not complete in that activity

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the Application class in android. It is a singleton class, so whatever value you set there, can be accessed from another activity.

You can access ur application instance like this in every activity

```
MyApplication appContext = (MyApplication)getApplicationContext();
```

And inside the manifest file add the attribute to the application tag

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Comment: is it call same way as  we call new activity like using intent because i want to call this as next activity at starting of application for fetch all data.and i wan to show the progress dialog continuesly till all data fetch.so can i use the async class in this application class?

Comment: In the beginning of an activity use async task to fetch ur data. Once the data is received, set the values to ur application object 'appContext'. Then u can access those values in any activity with the above code. Since application object is singleton, the values u set in one activity will be available in the other activities. Refer this http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: in async i have call the server api but if the connection is not there then my application will crach but instead of i want to show the user that connection problem then how can i do that?

Comment: and also the problem is that when i can the api for fetch dat from server then i need some value from user then it will call.but the application class will call at luanch time so it have not any value at that time so what can i do?